# How to delete a snapshot in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, snapshot

What's the correct way to delete a snapshot in HDFS? Such as the follow:

```
/folder/path/.snapshot/snapshot-20160101
```

[From documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsSnapshots.html#Delete_Snapshots) I can see there's a command

```
hdfs dfs -deleteSnapshot <path> <snapshotName>
```

but not entirely sure how to use it.

Is `/folder/path/.snapshot/` the `<path>` and `snapshot-20160101` the `<snapshotName>`?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: just remove the /.snapshot from the path and it work

Answer (score 2):

Yes @[oulwj12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9844001/oulwj12), you are right.

The path is `/folder/path/` and the name is `snapshot-20160101`. Please note that according the referenced documentation path means the path of the snapshottable directory.

So your command should be something like

```
hdfs dfs -deleteSnapshot /folder/path/ snapshot-20160101
```

Comment: thanks, just a quick follow up. if I take a full snapshot then delete it right after it is not going to delete all the files right?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a little difficulty with the same and I tried it on my cluster so here we go :

> hdfs dfs -deleteSnapshot /path/  (just before .snapshot folder starts, don't mention .snapshot) snapshot-xxxxx(snapshot name is .snapshot directory)